# CSS rCharts adjustments overlap the staggerLabel function in R renderChart{}

Tags: css, r, shiny, rendering, rcharts

The names on the **xAxis** are too long, and are overlapping each other, and it can be seen in this image:
[xAxis Labels overlapping - Yaxis numbers are fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5F7X.jpg)

I am plotting a **discreteBarChart** with **rCharts** package, where **xAxis** contains *Names* and **yAxis** contains *numbers*
the numbers on the **yAxis** are too long *(9 digits)* and not shown all, so I had to do some **CSS edits** to show them correctly, after doing so, the argument ***"staggerLabels = TRUE"*** looses its effect in the xAxis, means the names on the **xAxis** are overlapping each other because i included CSS customization for the yAxis for numbers

this is how it looked like before adding the CSS lines:
[xAxis good labels- Yaxis numbers not shown all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGKX.jpg)

any help please to prevent overlapping? or to view the Labels on the xAxis in an diagonal line?

**server.r**

```
    output$top10Clients <- renderChart({

    topclients <- 
      arrange(ct %>%  
                group_by(as.character(Customer)) %>% 
                summarise(
                  CTo = sum(as.numeric(`Net turnover`))
                ), desc(CTo))
    colnames(topclients)[colnames(topclients)=="as.character(Customer)"] <- "Customer"

    topclients <- subset(topclients[1:10,], select = c(Customer, CTo))

    p <- nPlot(CTo~Customer, data = topclients, type = "discreteBarChart", dom = "top10Clients")
    p$params$width <- 1000
    p$params$height <- 200
    p$xAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE)
    p$yAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE, width = 50)

    return(p)
  })
```

**custom.css**

```
.nv-discreteBarWithAxes .nvd3 > g > g > text,
.nv-axisMaxMin text {
  transform: translateX(13px); 

}
```

would be so pleased for any help or hint 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add below properties to each

```css
div.a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
<div class="a">Test World!</div>
<br>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @NPE, it is working good, any hint on how to break the link when the name is too long ?

Comment: use below css property <word-break: break-all;> it will specifies how words should break when reaching the end of a line.

Comment: i've added it, but didn't work 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

   .nv-discreteBarWithAxes .nvd3 > g > g > text,
.nv-axisMaxMin text {
  transform: translateX(13px); 
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg); 
  word-break: break-word;
}


<!-- end snippet -->